# How do I match from multiple starting nodes to the closest n nodes of a particular type per row?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, breadth-first-search

I'm looking for a way to do breadth-first-search or shortest path from some start node(s) to a kind of node (whether by label or by property), and to stop when I find the first match (or n matches, if I could have that as a parameter).

I'd like to know if a solution exists with Cypher itself, and if not, if there are existing procedures (from APOC or some other source) to do this, and if not, how I might implement this (using the traversal framework maybe?)

The shortestPath() algorithms, both from neo4j itself and the APOC libraries, work best when you know your start and end nodes, or if you want to match based upon all possible start or end nodes.

But when we don't know our end nodes specifically, and we want to simply find the first node matching some predicates or labels (or nodes, if we allow the number we want to find to be parameterized), those procedures don't seem to work well.

For example, let's say I have a social graph of :Persons with [:Knows] relationships between them, and a [:LivesIn] relationship between :Persons and :City. Lastly, :Persons are additionally labeled with their occupation (so a :Person who is a doctor is also labeled with :Doctor)

With this example graph, for a given :City, for all :Persons in that city, I want to find the shortest path of each :Person following [:Knows] relationships to a :Doctor. As output I want to see each :Person, their closest :Doctor, the number of [:Knows] hops to that :Doctor, ordered by the number of hops descending.

My query, if I was using the neo4j shortest path, could look something like this:

```
MATCH (c:City)<-[:LivesIn]-(p:Person)
WHERE c.name = "San Diego"
WITH p
MATCH path = shortestPath( (p)-[:Knows*]-(d:Doctor) )
...
```

At this point we have rows pairing every person to every single doctor in the graph, and the shortest paths between all of them. As far as what to do next, I might collect all paths so we are back to one row per :Person, then order all collections by path length ascending, then for each user take the head of the path collection, then output the :Person, their closest :Doctor, and the number of hops between them.

That's not efficient at all. I want the shortest path to the closest :Doctor, and to stop searching once that first :Doctor node is found.

If an easy solution exists, I'd additionally like to know if supports other options (finding based on predicates and properties, not just labels), and if the number of matches I want it to find can be parameterized (if I want to find the closest 2 doctors, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APOC has matured quite a bit, and now has answers to these kinds of requirements.

Using `apoc.path.expandConfig()` (and other path expander procedures) it's now possible to expand out to nodes with certain labels, and stop further expansion once a given limit is reached (such as requesting the n closest doctors per person).

Using `apoc.cypher.run()`, it's now possible to perform a Cypher query with a LIMIT, and that limit will apply to the results per-row instead of limiting all rows. This is good for more complicated cases where node labels and relationship types alone aren't enough to describe the traversal or the nodes needed, such as when property evaluation is needed.

Both approaches are demonstrated in this [Neo4j knowledge base entry](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use LIMIT 1 in the return statement?

Comment: My understanding is that this only filters the output, and does not actually halt the search. My question is about improving the performance of the search, specifically avoiding the cartesian product by expanding out and halting when we've found the specified number of results. Even if we use LIMIT 1 the search will still get less and less performant the more nodes exist on the paths I'm searching on.

Comment: The other reason this won't work is for cases when we're matching from multiple :Person nodes (such as in my example) instead of a single person. I'm not looking for a single row back, I want a single row per :Person with their closest doctor.

Comment: I think ... someone else can clarify ... the limit 1 will stop the search. In terms of the second point, have you considered using REDUCE to create a concatenated string and then restricting it to the shortest string length? For example, here's a query I used to find ancestors sharing an X-chromosome of a person; it's inherited from either a mother (either sex) or father (daughters only).

Comment: here's a query   "match p=(n:Person{RN:12 & "})-[:father|mother*..20]->(m) with m, reduce(status ='', q IN nodes(p)| status + q.sex) AS c, reduce(srt2 ='|', q IN nodes(p)| srt2 + q.RN + '|') AS PathOrder where c=replace(c,'MM','') return m.RN,m.fullname as Name, c,PathOrder ORDER BY LENGTH(c),c desc"

Comment: see also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952175/neo4j-cypher-query-for-x-chromosome-ancestors/34955488?noredirect=1#comment57659641_34955488

Comment: see also https://neo4j.com/blog/common-confusions-cypher/ for how to use [..n] to filter out rows in a collection. This might also help?